# Showing (AUB)∩(BUC)∩(CUA)=(A∩B)U(A∩C)U(B∩C)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that A∪(B∩C)=(A∪B)∩(A∪C). I feel like I'm supposed to apply this to this question, but I'm really confused by all the terms. So far I have:

(A∪B)∩(B∪C)∩(C∪A)=(B∪A)∩(B∪C)∩(C∪A)=B∪(A∩C)∩(C∪A)

I seem to be stuck and I have no idea how to further proceed from here, or if I'm even solving it right. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It might be easier just to draw a Venn diagram; verify that both sides produce the same diagram.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\left(A\cap C\right)\cup\left(B\cap C\right)&=\Big(A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)\Big)\cap \Big(C\cup\left(B\cap C\right)\Big)\\
&=\Big(A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)\Big)\cap \Big(\left(C\cup B\right)\cap\left(C\cup C\right)\Big)\\
&=\Big(A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)\Big)\cap \left(C\cup B\right)\\
&=\Big(A\cap \left(C\cup B\right)\Big)\cup\Big(\left(B\cap C\right)\cap \left(C\cup B\right)\Big)\\
&=\left(A\cap C\right) \cup\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\Big(B\cap C\cap \left(C\cup B\right)\Big)\\
&=\left(A\cap C\right) \cup\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(B\cap C\right).\\\\
\left(A\cap C\right)\cup\left(B\cap C\right)&= \Big(\left(A\cap C\right)\cup B\Big)\cap\Big(\left(A\cap C\right)\cup C\Big)\\
&= \left(A\cup B\right)\cap\left(C\cup B\right)\cap\Big(\left(A\cup C\right)\cap\left(C\cup C\right)\Big)\\
&= \left(A\cup B\right)\cap\left(C\cup B\right)\cap\left(A\cup C\right).
\end{align*}